# Let emacs choose mode conditionally when opening files

Tags: emacs

I use the php debugger *geben* and *nxhtml-mode* -- my standard mode for editing php files.  Unfortunately, these two modes don't mix well.  Is it possible to configure emacs such a way that it enables nxhtml only conditionaly, when I open php files manually, but enables *php-mode* instead when the buffer is opened by geben?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I seem to have fixed it.  Warning! I really don't know what I'm doing -- these are my first steps in lisp and I found it by trial and error.  I've added this to the end of my .emacs file:

```
(require 'geben)
(defun geben-enter-php-mode ()
  (let* ((local-path (buffer-file-name))
     (session (and local-path (geben-source-find-session local-path))))
    (if session
        (let ((session nil))
          (php-mode)))))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'geben-enter-php-mode)
```